# What possible steps could be taken to fight racism in the police?

Tags: law, police, racism

Within the US, what steps could be taken to try to prevent racism in the police?

For example, there is no strong 'test' for racism that can't be double-guessed. Even then, there is the potential that some racist high ranking officers would be more lenient to racist cops due to their own racist views.

Comment: I think this question is impossibly broad, but [here's a start](https://www.vox.com/2020/6/1/21277013/police-reform-policies-systemic-racism-george-floyd).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you point out, there's no way to "test" for racism, and even if there were, firing people based solely on that would be uncomfortably close to punishing someone for "thought crimes". That's why people who try to tackle this problem don't try to eliminate prejudice, but to restructure and reform the system of policing so that the prejudices of individual officers or society at large don't have racist outcomes. There are lots ideas out there and many of them need to be tested in real world settings, but here's a overview of just a few:

- **Accountability:** In any organization, it's inevitable that there will be some "bad apples" who abuse their power. [The problem with the police, is that bad cops are almost always protected by prosecutors and their fellow officers and are rarely held accountable](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/why-its-still-so-rare-for-police-officers-to-face-legal-consequences-for-misconduct/). Victims of police abuse can sue for civil damages, but since [almost all (99.8%!) of this money is paid by the government](https://www.nyulawreview.org/issues/volume-89-number-3/police-indemnification/) (that is to say, the taxpayers), these settlements don't do anything to discourage these abuses. If police officers who abuse their power, whether in racially motivated ways or not, were held accountable then 1) there would be fewer bad cops and 2) people could better accept mistakes and lapses as just that.
- **Better training:** One of the major aims of recent protests is the [demilitarization of the police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Militarization_of_police). In addition to the increasing use of automatic weapons and armored vehicles, [which are disproportionately deployed in minority neighborhoods](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/science/police-militarization-fails-to-protect-officers-and-targets-black-communities-study-finds), many police departments have embraced a more aggressive and violent philosophy of policing that depicts police as ["at war" with the public](https://www.insider.com/bulletproof-dave-grossman-police-trainer-teaching-officers-how-to-kill-2020-6). This "Warrior Mentality" is best illustrated by [Dave Grossman's *Bulletproof* courses on "Killology"](https://www.killology.com) as well as William Lewinski's [Force Science Institute](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/02/us/training-officers-to-shoot-first-and-he-will-answer-questions-later.html).
  As long as police see their job as "us-vs-them", then their conscious and unconscious biases will influence who they see as "the enemy" and lead to both general and racially biased abuses. If police could be trained to instead adopt a "protect and serve" mentality, the thinking goes, they might be better able to empathize and work with the public.
- **Off-loading police functions and decriminalization:** If we accept that, in the real world, policing is going to continue to be applied in a racially biased manner, then by reducing, where possible, the extent of policing and the damage caused by minor encounters with the police, we can reduce the effect of this prejudice.

  - One way to do that is to decriminalize minor offenses like marijuana
    possession. While marijuana criminalization is not, in itself,
    racist, but since [Blacks are arrested for marijuana possession at
    4x the rate of whites](https://www.aclu.org/report/report-war-marijuana-black-and-white?redirect=criminal-law-reform/war-marijuana-black-and-white), despite using drugs at the same rates,
    the outcome of these laws is racially biased.
  - Another way is to [transfer social support functions from the police to civilian and community groups](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/what-would-it-mean-defund-police-these-cities-offer-ideas-n1229266). Tasks like monitoring the homeless, helping people with mental illness or drug addiction, or enforcing school rules could be carried out by social workers who are better able to help these people, rather than forcing these tasks onto the police whose training (understandably) pushes them towards more aggressive and punitive responses.

Comment: The problem with personal accountability is that there should **also** be incentives for the department and the officer to admit error. If they get slapped with huge damages unless they fort up, they fort up. *Police: support them when they are right, train them when they make honest mistakes, come down on them like a ton of bricks when they are deliberately wrong.*

Comment: @o.m.: But part of the problem is that we have a TV and movie industry that glorifies bad cops.  "Dirty Harry", "Miami Vice", and hundreds if not thousands more.

Comment: @o.m. That's a good point, and I try to get at something like that with the last sentence of that section. We're in a sort of vicious cycle where cops "fort up" which destroys any trust the public might have in them, which makes them less likely to be accepting of legitimate mistakes, which leads to cops getting more defensive, etc. If people trusted that real bad actors would be held accountable, they would be more understanding of actual mistakes and more likely to believe that they were, in fact, mistakes).

Comment: @divibisan, a random, untested idea: if a police department admits an error on the first, internal/administrative review, some (most?) of the damages are paid by the Federal budget. If they go to court, damages come from their own municipal budget. So there is a strong financial incentive for the *department* to admit mistakes. And in an unrelated measure, any fines imposed by the cops or local courts go directly *into* the federal budget. So when they write a ticket, you know that it *costs* the department money for the administrative overhead, it doesn't bring them money.

Comment: @o.m. Yeah, I like that idea. While we're spitballing, what if the reimbursement rate was also tied to the officer's record, so officers who accumulate more complaints and problems become progressively more expensive, giving them an incentive to replace them or move them to desk jobs etc. where they're less likely to abuse the public.

Comment: @divibisan, that would encourage a department with such an officer *not* to admit any error, and to gamble on going to court even in questionable cases. My idea was to encourage the department to go to court only if they are overwhelmingly sure that the court will vindicate their actions.

Answer (score -2):

The quesion is based on a misconception: that police generally ARE racist.  But a little research shows that black cops are perfectly willing to mistreat or even kill other black people, and that cops of any color are likewise willing to mistreat/kill poor white people.  That suggests that the problem is in fact the general attitude of cops towards the civilian population.

The appearance of racism is mostly due to cultural factors, which might be the product of past racism in society.  Black people, particularly poorer ones, are likely to live in mostly black urban neighborhoods where they are likely to frequently encounter cops.  OTOH, many poorer* white people tend to live in more rural areas, and so can go years between encounters.  Thus if the numbers of poor blacks and poor whites are equal, and there is the same probability that a given cop/civilian interaction will turn out badly, the resulting numbers will APPEAR to be caused by cops' racism, even though they're not.

*Like any bully, cops prefer to pick on those they perceive as weak.

Comment: This non-answer confuses the existing institutional racism of police forces with individual conscious racism.  It's similar to the *"some of my best friends are..."* defense used by oblivious bigots for at least a century.  Or using the existence of the [Association of German National Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_of_German_National_Jews) as evidence that the Germany of the 1930s therefore couldn't really be racist.

Comment: I think your main point is a very good one, but I don't think you can say from that that police aren't racism. Black people can be racist, even against other Black people, and particularly when you consider unconscious racism. Also, as agc points out, institutional racism plays into the factors you discuss. It's not just chance that minority neighborhoods are policed more aggressively.

Comment: @jamesqf The idea that the premise is wrong isn't really the matter. You're questioning the idea that there is a need for more measures to prevent racism in the force. That's irrelevant to finding an actual method to reduce racism in the force. Of course this is with the assumption that there is _a_ degree of racism (which there is indeniably is)

Comment: @yolo: No, what I'm questioning is the idea that racism is the primary source of the current problems, when in fact those problems are normal police behavior in any place and time where they are not under sufficient restraint.  You can easily find the same sorts of police behavior in societies that are racially & ethnically homogeneous. Police work tends to attract bullies, bullies pick on those they see as weak, which generally equates to poor.

Comment: @jamesqf even then. Whether most problems are due to this or racism isn't the concern of the question. The question concerns problems related to racism (of which needs not be the maun cause of problems to make the question answerable)